# How to check log for an event rule in aws cloud watch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch

I have scheduled one event rule 'Start_EC2_Instances_Everyday_at_530_PM' which triggers one lambda function to start some instances in a region. I have tested lambda function and it is working perfectly.

The next trigger dates are also showing as expected,[image]

but when I checked it didn't start the instance.

Now I am trying to check the logs in Show metrics for the rule but it says rule did not meet any metrics[image]

Comment: Does your CloudWatch event have required permissions to invoke the lambda?

Comment: I believe even CloudWatch event doesn't permission to invoke lambda, the metric should still show but failed for invocation

Comment: I'd like to you contact Support team from AWS to see what happening. And please try https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/CWE_Troubleshooting.html#RuleDidNotTrigger

Comment: Where I can add permission to the event rule to trigger Lambda function? 

I am triggering event rule from my own aws account. 
I can see the option of adding permission in event buses where I can add permission for some other external aws account.

Thanks,
Sambhav

Comment: Also just an update, I was able to test the event rule by running at fixed run at 1 minute and it worked fine. Exploring further to debug the issue.

Best,
Sambhav

Comment: My bad, I considered GMT time 5 hours and 30 minutes ahead instead of behind. Also going to answer the question, where to find cloud watch logs as able to figure out the same. 

Thanks for the help Nrai, NghiaDo

Answer (score 2):

**Cloud watch logs can be checked under cloudwatch > Logs > Log Groups[![enter image description here**][![enter image description here][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y88FR.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y88FR.jpg)

**Click on the rule for which you want to see the log and click on the specific log which you want to see** [image]

P.S. Regarding the issue, it happened becuase of confusion in considering GMT time ahead (instead) of IST.